# MaterialDatePicker todayInUtcMilliseconds method returning incorrect day

Tags: android, material-components

When creating a `MaterialDatePicker` using the `MaterialDatePicker.todayInUtcMilliseconds()` method, our app is returning a timestamp that is a day out from the current date.

The simplified code we are using to display the `MaterialDatePicker` is as follows:

```
val picker: MaterialDatePicker<Long> = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker()
        .setInputMode(MaterialDatePicker.INPUT_MODE_CALENDAR)
        .setSelection(MaterialDatePicker.todayInUtcMilliseconds())
        .setTitleText("Custom title")
        .build()

        picker.run {
            addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(viewModel::updateContractDate)
            show(parentActivity.supportFragmentManager, picker.toString())
        }
```

Which, when displayed, is showing yesterdays date as selected (6 July) as seen below:

[image]

This is *especially* odd as the same sample code returns **correctly on the same device** when used in the Material Component library's sample 'catalog' app.

We are using the latest Material Library version 1.3.0-alpha01 and have observed this on Android 10 - API 29 and Android 8.1 - API 27. We are also utilizing Jake Wharton's ThreeTen Android Backport elsewhere in the app, but I am not sure if that is relevant.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/882

Comment: Thank you @GabrieleMariotti - that is exactly what the issue is

Comment: I has the similar issue, here is solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69662808/449007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to be a [bug](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1360) as of the latest Material Component Library version 1.3.0-alpha01. It has been fixed but was not put into the build.

The [suggested solution](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1360#issuecomment-644790081) is to use a 'daily build' of the library by using the following in the top-level `build.gradle` file

```
    maven {
        name = "MaterialSnapshots"
        url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/material-components/material-components-android")
        credentials {
            username = <github_username>
            password = <github_access_token>
        }
    }
```

and using the `1.3.0-dev-20200619` version as a dependency

Answer (score 0):

It was a [bug](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/882) opened again with another [bug](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1360).
Now it is fixed starting from the version [**`1.2.0-rc01`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/d9b98743e5b6ab13f1e256619da5fcf2e0d8f50a) and **`1.3.0-alpha02`**.

[image]

Comment: See my answer above, it's not fixed in 1.3.0-alpha01

Comment: The 1.2.0-rc01 was released after the 1.3.0-alpha01. The 1.3.0-alpha01 is still not fixed

Comment: This issue still exists in Material Library.  Not fixed.